# Stack md-chips vertically angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-chip

I'm testing out the md-chips directive in AngularJS.

Is there any way of stacking the 'chips' vertically instead of appending the chips horizontally?

I have been trying out the demos found here:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips

Answer (score 2):

The following CSS style is the minimum needed to enable chips to stack vertically:

```
md-chip {
  clear: left;
}
```

The default CSS of md-chip's is
      `float: left` and applying `clear: left` causes the chips to clear each other and stack vertically. Applying `float: none` or some other styles to change the float appears to easily break the default directive and causes one to be unable to access the input field and add new chips. I note that some other styles may need to be applied to fix the `.md-chips` container containing the chips such as limiting its width to get the desired result.

See: [Vertically Stacking Chips Demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/airbridge/pen/bqEMzV)